# how to create drop down list with html and css only?

Tags: html, css

I want to know easiest way to create drop down list with html and css only.

Answer (score 5):

Use the select tag.

```
<select>
    <option>red</option>
    <option>green</option>
    <option>blue</option>
    <option>yellow</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

**css**

```
<style type="text/css">
select.mySelect{}
select.mySelect option{}
</style>
```

**html**

```
<select class="mySelect">
<option>Display</option>
</select>
```